# Good way to elevate and secure irrigation anti-siphon valves

Tags: code-compliance, pvc, sprinkler-system, irrigation

My anti-siphon valves need to be 18 inches (half a meter) off the ground, due to local code, the water source and the slope of the yard. There are three valves connected to a horizontal manifold and I was given mounting brackets to screw down over the manifold. So now the trouble is, what to screw them to? This isn't very close to the house or I'd affix a board on the wall and screw the pipe to that.

Does anyone have experience designing and building something solid to hold the irrigation valves up? The incoming pipe and the manifold itself are nowhere near strong enough for the valves to just hold themselves up, and the outgoing pipes are flexible by design.

Comment: go to hardware store and get 1x1 inch square tube, and hammer it in the ground

Comment: Does local code have any approved ways, or just do it?  A few ways to do it but local code might say no to most of them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that any code requiring plumbing bits to stick 18" out of the ground would also be fairly particular about how they're stuck out of the ground and what they're attached to.

If they're not particular about how you do it, I'd use any sort of galvanized fence post, that is locally available and cost effective. Pound that into the ground with a post ram<sup>*</sup>, then cut it off ~20" above the ground.

Attach a cross bar to this (a U-bolt around the post, through the cross bar, and held in place with a couple of nuts), then attach your manifold to the cross bar through the mounting holes. You may need to substitute nuts & bolts for the mounting screws, or switch to machine screws and tap the holes in your cross bar. Adapt as necessary.

If you don't feel this will be quite sturdy enough, use two posts with the cross bar between them.

Put a bit of landscaping around it to make it look nicer than a mandated eye-sore in the middle of the lawn.

---

<sup>*</sup>The proper term is escaping me at the moment. A piece of steel tubing, capped at one end, with two handles. You fit it over the top of the post, lift, and slam it down onto the top of the post to slowly hammer it into the ground. Easier and more accurate than swinging a sledge hammer at the top. Also, safer for the person holding the post, should you miss with said sledge.

Comment: We call that a "post driver" or colloquially "post pounder" but I knew exactly what you meant by "post ram" too.

Comment: Wow... You know those days that you have sometimes... I've even had several cups of coffee this morning, @FredricShope, and _still_ couldn't come up with "post driver"... Thanks.